# Bitrix.Множественные поля и инфоблоки для модуля

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день.
Дали задание на создание модуля.Суть работы модуля заключается в определении схожих товаров и записи ссылок всех похожих товаров в товар. 
В самом заголовке есть текст "Добавить множественное поле «Похожие товары» в инфоблок «Товары» для хранения ссылок на похожие товары. Необходимо проанализировать инфоблок «товары» на предмет выявления по наименованию схожих товаров.
Для чего добавлять множественное поле в инфоблок?Как проанализировать инфоблок?Я вижу,что там написано про хранение ссылок,но ответов это не дает :)

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит изучить [курсы](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/) по Битрикс судя по вопросу вы даже базовые понятия не понимаете, дальше будет очень сложно.

Множественное свойство. - это свойство любого типа (строка, дата, привязка к элементам инфоблока и т.п.) которое может хранить не одно, а несколько значений. В форме добавления свойств есть специальная галка для этого "Множественное". Если подходить к вашей задаче буквально "хранить ссылки на похожие товары" -то тип строка, если более правильно делать - Привязка к элементам инфоблока.

Проанализировать. Обойти все товары по элементно и найти похожие по заданным критериям. Для учебных целей возможно вам будет достаточно функции PHP [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.similar-text.php). И принять при каком значении (возвращаемым этой функцией) считать товары одинаковыми.

Comment: Большое спасибо